# Angular - Angular.js not being recognized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm

I'm new to Angular, and trying to do a simple Hello World. Please find my source files below:

```
<html >
  <head>
    <script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <title>ngClassifieds</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ngClassifieds">
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-init="yourName = 'oie'" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**..\ngClassifieds\scripts\app.js**

```
angular.module("ngClassifieds",[]);
```

File Structure currently in place (created using npm)

```
└───ngClassifieds
    │   index.html
    │   package.json
    │
    ├───css
    ├───node_modules
    │   ├───angular
    │   │       angular-csp.css
    │   │       angular.js
    │   │       angular.min.js
    │   │       angular.min.js.gzip
    │   │       angular.min.js.map
    │   │       bower.json
    │   │       index.js
    │   │       LICENSE.md
    │   │       package.json
    │   │       README.md
```

**I'm currently facing two issues:**

1. If I set ng-app to ng-app="ngClassifieds" in the index.html file, Angular stops working (see output below)
2. If I use the \ngClassifieds\node_modules\angular\angular.js file, instead of https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js, it stops working (see output below)

**Error:**
[image]

Whereas if I remove the ng-app parameter and use https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js instead, it works as expected:

[image]

This is the working **index.html**:

```
<html >
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <title>ngClassifieds</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-init="yourName = 'oie'" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's your `ng-controller`?

Comment: I don't have one. I'm following the steps described here https://school.scotch.io/getting-started-with-angularjs-1x/making-a-hello-world-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you defined a module, you acually don't include it in your file and that's why it gives an error. Since it wasn't include the module that's it's trying to look for (`ngClassifieds`) doesn't exist. Just include your `app.js` file in your header after angular and it will run:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/ngClassifieds/scripts/app.js"></script> <!-- Include it here-->
    <title>ngClassifieds</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ngClassifieds">
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-init="yourName = 'oie'" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDITED**

As pointed out, the path to the app.js file was wrong. After fixing it, it worked.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't go before:



<html >
  <head>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="ngClassifieds/scripts/app.js"></script>

    <title>ngClassifieds</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ngClassifieds">
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-init="yourName = 'oie'" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where you `app.js` file is located. Is it being loaded in correctly (*along with angular*)?

Comment: My app.js file is under \ngClassifieds\scripts\app.js

Comment: @user1829136 Also try using the CDN for angular instead of your local directory (*it seems like the path might not be valid or the angular file isn't loading*), in that case is it working?

Comment: Spencer, thanks! I just now realized that the path to the app.js file was wrong... I'm sorry I had missed that detail! Thanks a lot!